# Error: inherits(doc, "TextDocument") is not TRUE

Tags: r, term-document-matrix

I am running the following code chunk

```
tdm = TermDocumentMatrix(ctext,control=list(minWordLength=1))
print(tdm)

inspect(tdm[10:20,11:18])

out = findFreqTerms(tdm,lowfreq=5)
print(out)
```

When I run it in console it runs fine. However when I include it as part of a RMD and try to Knit HTML (ioslides) I get an error:

Error:

> inherits(doc, "TextDocument") is not TRUE

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit your post and provide a full example with which readers can reproduce your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.

The problem is basically with the version of **tm** package. You can't really help it.

Use `content_transformer` function in `tm_map` function. It resolved the error for me.

Hope it helps.